# Reset errors in Knockout validation in step-by-step wizard

Tags: javascript, validation, knockout.js

I have created a step by step wizard using knockout and the template bind and now I want to force the user to complete each page before going to next, and by completing I mean Knockout validate must be valid. 
The next-button is enabled when there is no error on the viewmodel and it works fine when stepping through the wizard but the problem occurs when you go into one step and press previous. The errors kept "alive" even when you go back, so the next-button on page 1 are disabled because page 2 are invalid.

I've setup a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1uo8rtw2/1/

1. Write something in the name box
2. Press next
3. Press previous
4. Now you see the Next-button is disabled.

Is suppose the problem is in the code below:

```
    self.errors = ko.validation.group(self.viewModel);

    self.PrevIsEnabled = ko.observable(false);
    self.NextIsEnabled = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.errors().length == 0 && self.SelectedTemplate() != "Age";
    });
```

Is there any way one can reset error-count when going back and force knockout validation to re-validate the current template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've stumbled upon [this pull request at github](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/pull/433),
so all I have to do is subscribe to `SelectedTemplate` and call

```
self.errors.clearAllErrors();
```

and it works.

I cannot get my updated JSFiddle to work because i cannot implement the new function but here is the ground though of it all http://jsfiddle.net/1uo8rtw2/2/

Answer (score 0):

`self.errors` contains the errors for all fields.

You should check only current template field validity:

```
self.NextIsEnabled = ko.computed(function() {
    var selectedTemplate = self.SelectedTemplate();
    return selectedTemplate != "Age" 
           && self.viewModel[selectedTemplate].isValid();
}
```

Of course, if you have more than one field in a template, you should check for the validity of all of them.

Comment: I see what you do there, but if this is a more complex wizard with 5 steps and 10 different fields in each step, I would like to not have to hard code each piece of check myself. Is there any way to loop through all fields bound to a observable inside a template?

Comment: You can create a separate viewmodel for each template, with its group validation, all included in one parent viewmodel.

Comment: There is no other way? I guess making one view model for each step actually makes the most sense in the long run...?

Comment: No one else with suggestions? If i have 5 steps with 5 supsteps, that would be 25 viewmModels, and it is hard to maintain after a while